# Radio button not inline

Tags: css

I have 3 radio button with css property of  margin-top: -27px; This cause the 2 radio button to move above the main label header where as the other 1 i correct as it is beside the radio button label and beneath the main label of radio button. How do I limit or force the other 2 radio button not exceeding certain limit and stay same height line with the 3rd radio button.

Comment: Pls share your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please put your code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand what you're talking about completely. As the others pointed out, you need to post your code if you want the best help.

However, if you want to try and align the 3 radio buttons, you could wrap them in a div and set the individual elements to inline.

So here would be your elements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="radio" class="inline-button">
    <input type="radio" class="inline-button">
    <input type="radio" class="inline-button">
</div>
```

And you could style them like this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.inline-button {
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your problem. I think You need this one. This will help you some times.

```
.test-class {display:inline !important; margin:5px !important}
```

Use this class for your main div related radio buttons. I hope this helps you!